# What is the best way to "roll back" changes?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, atomic

Alright, so I have a Spring application that takes in a Network Representation and boots up virtual machines to represent the network that was passed in.

It uses a low level API to bring up the VMs, there is no database involved.

What I need to figure out how to do is handle the situation where a user submits a 10 node (or any number) network model and the application goes through and builds up the network (starting VMs), if a node fails to startup I want to be able to react to that. I would like to be able to roll back my changes (i.e destroy all nodes that were created).

I've been told that I need to look into "Transactions" but I am unsure whether or not that applies to this scenario when I'm not using a database.

As a side note, I do have logic to take down nodes if a user sends in that request.

My question is -- how do I handle this?

Also, is this the best stack overflow for this question?

Comment: there's only one Stack*Overflow*, and yes, this seems like the appropriate Stack*Exchenge* for this question :) It's a good one, by the way. My instinct would be to utilize the existing `Transaction` framework as well - because, as you hint, it's designed to do exactly what you're talking about here but with regard to database operations. I suspect you could adapt it to make it work for you here, as well.

Comment: Maybe [Computer Science StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is a better choice.

Comment: Whoops! My apologies, I did mean "StackExchange" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem that you are looking for transactional behavior, and specifically, for atomicity ("all or nothing"). But usually "transaction" connotes certain guarantees (particularly around ACID properties) that will be difficult or impossible to achieve where human-level timescales on the order of minutes are involved.

Probably "workflow with compensation for errors" is more what you would be looking for here.

I would implement this manually, perhaps with tool support (e.g. workflow engines). Kick off a process to spawn your network, and keep track of the current progress, such as VMs created, VMs in progress, etc. If there are errors that demand a rollback, then have another process that performs a cleanup. The behavior of the cleanup process itself could fail, so it might retry its various steps a couple times before generating a report that says "this cleanup step failed".

If there are shared resources involved then you would need to implement some kind of isolation mechanism as well. Sometimes this is easy enough--e.g., DHCP helps you avoid duplicate IPs. If you're updating a DNS zone file then you'd want to synchronize access to that to avoid concurrent writes. Etc.

Comment: I think I agree with you, Willie Wheeler.